# I'm new to this and i need help please <3

Tags: discord.js

So basically when i run a command, the bot spams its response.

```
    bot.on('message', message => {
        let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

        switch (args[0]){
            case 'embed':
                const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    .setTitle('User Information')
                    .addField('Player Name', message.author.username)
                    .addField('Version', version)
                    .addField('Current Server', message.guild.name)
                    .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
                    .setFooter('Made By NotBanEvading')

                message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
                break;


        }


    })
```

https://gyazo.com/a1c71fc097e1253bc036d1ef293f034e

Answer (score 1):

`bot.on('message', message =>..` means an event when the bot receives **any** messages.
Which means it will trigger when it recieves message from itself or other bots.

You can check if the message's author is  a bot using `message.author.bot`, like so:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    // Do nothing if the message is from a bot.
    if (message.author.bot) { return; }

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    // ... Rest of your codes
```

(P.S please make your title clearer on what you are actually asking. Rather than stating that you need help.)

Comment: Thanks, helps very appreciated. Also i will be more descriptive in my titles next time.